# Touchpad buttons not working for a certain user

Tags: lenovo-laptop, windows-11, touchpad

Touchpad buttons are not working for my user only.

My laptop is: Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Nano.

For other administrator users, the touchpad buttons are working.

How can I resolve this?

I have tried reinstalling the touchpad drivers as administrator, but it says I have the same drivers already installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted my Windows account and then recreated it, which resolved the problem.